# Не воспринимает метод timeout() в discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Вот такая вот проблема: в дискорде появилась функция "Отправить подумать о своём поведении" (по типу мута).
**Конечно я хотел поставить её на бота:**

```
@bot.command()
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, reason):
    await member.timeout(until=time, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Участник {member.mention} был замучен.\nПричина: {reason}')
```

**Ошибка:**
`CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Пытался найти решение проблемы в интернете, не нашёл.

Comment: `pycord` и `discord.py` последней версии?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin как проверить?

Comment: pip show название библиотеки.  Или pip list. Или можете сразу попробовать обновить их

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin можете оставить ответ, поставлю галочку. Помогли, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы использовали не последнюю версию `pycord/discord.py`. В которой еще не было данной функции.

Решение обновить библиотеки

```
pip install -U py-cord discord.py
```